# display admob ad after scrolling webview to the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there anyway to display an admob ad only after the user scrolls the webview all the way to the bottom? I don't want it displaying on top of the webview since it will block the content or it will reduce the visible area. How should I modify my XML?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get webView content height using:

   ```
   int height = (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * webView.getScale());
   ```
2. Override the scroll method in webview to listen to scroll event, if the scroll reach the real height, webview is in the bottom of the scroll. Call `loadAd()` here.